# EWS Streaming Subscription System.Xml.XmlException

Tags: c#, xml, exception, exchangewebservices, exchange-server

I have a EWS Streaming Subscription that I want to constantly run.  It waits for a New Mail Event in a particular inbox and when the event fires it reads the email and POST's the contents to a different Web Service.  For the most part this works great, however every once this System.Xml.XmlException is thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: '▼', hexadecimal value 0
invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& e
32& outOrChars)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeTyp
)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.InternalReadEle
mespace xmlNamespace, String localName, XmlNodeType nodeType)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadRespo
viceXmlReader ewsXmlReader)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingServiceRequestBase.Pa
es(Object state)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(
te)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext execution
ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThr
kItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I have seen other posts about this exception but none seem to have solutions.  How can I stop this from being thrown?

UPDATE:

Just in case someone has the same problem.  We upgraded our server to 2010 sp2 and the problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: I'd love to but I can't re-create the exception while debugging so I dont no if the xml is in the email body, if its a response from the POST server, if its a response from the Exchange server during re-connect

Comment: You need to add logging to your exception handling.  Aka a `try{} catch{ Log.("current email/xml") }` kind of thing if your ever to reproduce/fix it.

Comment: all of my code is surrounded by `try{} catch(){}` exception handling

Comment: So when it catch's you need to take the xml it fails on and save it.

Comment: I understand that, and conceptually my code is set up to behave this way (all other exceptions are successfully managed this way).  However, instead of working like I'd imagine, the application fails and the above exception is displayed on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an internal error out of your control.

If the server is 2007 sp1 then upgrade it to 2010. If its 2010 verify its running with the latest service release patches.

If all that is done and it still occurs use your MSDN subscription (or the current support contract for the software) and contact Microsoft Support and have them look into it with you. They may have an unpublished service release which may fix this issue.